# Render Android layout into html div

Tags: java, android, cordova

Is it possible: to render a Android layout created by native java code into a HTML div using Phonegap? I know about the plugin concepts, but I dont'n know how to pass the layout to the webview to render it per javascript into one div.

All I found until now is how to shrink the Phonegap webview layout and add an additional layout. Then the both layouts are shown at the same time, but I would like to display the additional layout in the webview layout and control its position per javascript or css.

To render a specific view will also be sufficient, not the whole layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. There's nothing that i know of that will render a native view as HTML.

Comment: I didn't found nothing usefull until now. I dont't expect to have a valid html code to insert into a div but something like rendering stream from java view as a layer on top of webview content.